# VPN with client-to-client direct connectivity?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

When setting up a VPN, clients (say client1 and client2) usually authenticate to a server, and together the three constitute the VPN. When client1 wishes to send a packet to client2, this packet usually gets routed by way of server.

Are there products / configuration blueprints for products where it is possible to send packets directly from client1 to client2 without going though server? (if the underlying network topology permits it, e.g. no firewalls in the way)

If not, is there a way by which client1 can send a packet to client2 by way of server, without the server being able to snoop on the content of the packet? (E.g. because the packet is encrypted with the public key of client2)

I just asked in the OpenVPN forum, and the answer I got was "not with OpenVPN". So my question is: are there other products with which this is possible? Open-source preferred ...

One use case: client1 and client2, typically in separate offices, find themselves both at headquarters. Do they still need to talk to each other via the public internet?

Links appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure where they got their wisdom from when answering your question but OpenVPN can do this. I'm currently using it for a client-to-client vpn, no third machine required. In my case I'm able to connect (from work) directly to my home machine that is running a vpn listening process. It is the only machine I am interested in but I can also access all the other machines on my home network through the home machine.

Comment: @captcha: if I understand you correctly, your home machine is what I call the server, and your work machine the client. Now add a second client (say, another work machine). My question: can the second work machine send a packet to the first work machine over the VPN without going through your home server?

Comment: @captcha You're misunderstanding Johannes' question.

Comment: @Johannes Ernst thanks for clarifying this to me. Before switching over to OpenVPN I was using Tinc (www.tinc-vpn.org) and this worked fully peer-to-peer. I haven't used openvpn in this setup but I do read that it supports peer to peer.

Comment: @captcha: seems tinc does what I want. Any particular reason you moved to OpenVPN?

Comment: @Johannes Ernst I was using Tinc to connect three offices and it worked very well for many years, last year we simplified our firewall setup and chose IPSEC to have routing and vpn endpoints to be done in a single Cisco box per office. Since this is a non-opensource solution I didn't bother bringing this up in my comment. For home connectivity (1-to-n) I was using Tinc and have now moved to OpenVPN for no particular reason.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there products / configuration blueprints for products where it is possible to send packets directly from client1 to client2 without going though server? (if the underlying network topology permits it, e.g. no firewalls in the way)

I'm not aware of a shrinkwrapped solution, but this should be relatively easy to script. Outline:

- On client1, provide a service that reports its publicly addressable IP.
- On client1, run an OpenVPN service on its public IP.
- On client2, when connecting to the central OpenVPN server, have an "up" script connect to client1 and obtain its IP. Write this IP into an openvpn config snippet (e.g. "remote 1.2.3.4").
- On client2, start a new OpenVPN instance using a configuration that includes the above autogenerated snippet.

Of course, this isn't foolproof for a number of reasons (what if the service on client1 is not available? What if client2 connects to the central server before client1? etc.), but the principle is sound.

> is there a way by which client1 can send a packet to client2 by way of server, without the server being able to snoop on the content of the packet? (E.g. because the packet is encrypted with the public key of client2)

Yes. Establish a separate OpenVPN (or, heck, IPSec) session between client1 and client2. This sub-tunnel can use the other OpenVPN link as its transport.